# Memory management in game

Tags: android, memory, garbage-collection

My game is consuming memory a lot in my phone, how can I resolve this problem?

I've tried leave my `objects = null` in final and call the garbage collector, but not resolved.

The game have to create a new sprite a each one minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written your game creating sprite every minute, but i think rather to create new sprite replace the sprite image. if you are not doing any functional position operation on that sprite using below code.

```
spritetest.setTexture(CCTextureCache.sharedTextureCache().addImage("newimage.png"));
```

Answer (score 2):

What's consuming the bulk of memory in a Sprite is its texture not the object itself and as I can see in the cocos2d source for android they're cached (as IO is slow) by the TextureManager by matching filenames. Thus remember to free textures (mainly the big ones) with *TextureManager.removeTexture()* if you won't need them for a longer time (or re-loading doesn't hurt).

You should also consider implementing an [object pool](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool) for these sprites. This way you'd simply reuse unused instances instead of throwing them away just to create a new one the next moment.

In case you didn't know, the Android SDK comes with a tool called [*allocation tracker*](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/track-mem.html) (which by now is also integrated in the ADT) to analyze memory usage. The issue might not be where you expect it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to cleanup the previously created sprite or object of cocos2d.

```
removeChild(sprite1, true);
```

or

```
 sprite1.cleanup()
```

after that you can assign null to that object.

You can call the method

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().purgeCachedData();
```

to Removes cached all cocos2d cached data.